# NoClassDefFoundError in eclipse plugin execution

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, execution

I'm building eclipse plugin that uses JDT/AST.
Building the plugin works fine, but when I tried to run the plugin. I go this error message.
It complains that the ASTVisitor class is not found.

[image]

I checked the `org.eclipse.jdt.core***.jar` is in the build path with User Libraries.

[image]

What might be wrong? Do I need to setup execution path that points to jar files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse plugins manage dependencies using the `Manifest.MF` file. Check in the dependencies tab of your `Manifest.MF` file that you have `org.eclipse.jdt.core` as a required plugin.